# Does the newsletter go to myOpenID e-mail?

Tags: support, email, newsletter, myopenid

I was wondering, if I can leave my e-mail address out at my profile and still receive the newsletter from SO. I have changed from e-mail address lately and I don't know if the e-mail goes to my SO-profile-address or to the myOpenID address.

If it goes to myOpenID, can I leave my e-mail address out of my profile? I actually don't like it to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newsletter messages go to the email associated to your account, not to the email associated with your OpenID account.

Your email address is not shown to other users, which is what happens to some other details reported in your user profile. Compare the following two screenshots, which show what other users see in my profile page, and what I see.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Good to know, but not clear at the first sight. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your email address is never displayed. It is only shown when you view **your own** profile.

Click on [my profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155556/a-man-a-plan-a-canal-panama) and you will see.

Profile that I see (for me):

[image]

Comment: It could have been that you did not enter it. So that is always hard to verify. And for the other question: To what e-mail address does the newsletter go?

Comment: @Marnix see my update.